# Automatically display a toolTip in an ItemRenderer when the row is visible in the DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, tooltip, advanceddatagrid

I have an `AdvancedDataGrid` that uses `HierarchicalData` to display data in a tree format. For one of the columns, I'm using an `AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider` to conditionally display an image if certain conditions are met. I'm currently using the `ToolTipManager` to display additional information if the user mouses over the image.

**Here's what I would like to do:**

Instead of showing the `toolTip` when the user places their mouse over the image, I would like to automatically display the `toolTip` whenever the image is visible in the `AdvancedDataGrid`. If the user scrolls through the `AdvancedDataGrid`, the `toolTip` should move and follow along with its image accordingly.

Sample AdvancedDataGrid:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myAdvancedDataGrid" 
                        displayItemsExpanded="true"
                        allowMultipleSelection="false"
                        dataProvider="{myTreeData}"
                        draggableColumns="false"
                        depthColors="{[0xD6E5FF,0xFFFFFF]}"
                        folderClosedIcon="{null}" folderOpenIcon="{null}" defaultLeafIcon="{null}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colID" headerText="ID" dataField="myID"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colComments" headerText="Comments" dataField="comments"/>
    </mx:columns>
    <mx:rendererProviders>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider column="{colComments}" depth="2" dataField="comments" renderer="com.whatever.AdvancedDataGridCommentsRenderer" />
    </mx:rendererProviders>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

And the current AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
         paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="2"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off"
         height="22"
         horizontalAlign="center">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.ToolTip;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;
            [Embed(source="assets/myImage.png")]
            [Bindable]
            private var myIcon:Class;

            private var commentsToolTip:ToolTip;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                if (value["comments"] != null)
                {
                    if (value["comments"].toString().length > 0)
                    {
                        myImage.visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myImage.visible = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    myImage.visible = false;
                }

                validateDisplayList();
            }

            private function showToolTip(evt:Event, text:String):void
            {
                var pt:Point = new Point(evt.currentTarget.x, evt.currentTarget.y);

                // Convert the targets 'local' coordinates to 'global' -- this fixes the
                // tooltips positioning within containers.
                pt = evt.currentTarget.parent.contentToGlobal(pt);

                commentsToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(text, pt.x, pt.y, "errorTipAbove") as ToolTip;
                commentsToolTip.setStyle("borderColor", "#ff0000");
                commentsToolTip.setStyle("color", "white");
                var yOffset:int =  commentsToolTip.height + 5;
                commentsToolTip.y -= yOffset;
                commentsToolTip.x -= 5;
            }

            // Remove the tooltip
            private function killToolTip():void
            {
                ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(commentsToolTip);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Image id="myImage" 
              source="{myIcon}" 
              mouseOver="showToolTip(event, data['comments'].toString())" 
              mouseOut="killToolTip()" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the tooltip needs to be displayed all the time the image is displayed, it's not really a tooltip that you need, in that case you should just add a canvas/text field to your item renderer.

e.g.

```
<mx:HBox id="myContainer">
  <mx:Image id="myImage" 
          source="{myIcon}" 
          mouseOver="showToolTip(event, data['comments'].toString())" 
          mouseOut="killToolTip()" />
  <mx:Label text="Some text" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Then set change the calls to myImage.visible to myContainer.visible

However, for the quick and dirty fix, you already have everything you need, just make the calls in the set data override:

```
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;
            if (value["comments"] != null)
            {
                if (value["comments"].toString().length > 0)
                {
                    myImage.visible = true;
                    showToolTip(<params>);
                }
                else
                {
                    myImage.visible = false;
                    killToolTip(<params>);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myImage.visible = false;
            }

            validateDisplayList();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not married to the idea of using a toolTip. If there's a better method or component out there I'm open to that. The only issue I can potentially see with your solution is that the toolTip would get created when the data is set, but what happens when the user starts scrolling through the data grid? The rows would scroll, but the toolTip bubble would stay exactly where it was created wouldn't it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of the first implementation, you'll probably want to change it to display how you want it, but it should give you an idea of it. I'm not sure without testing whether or not the tooltip would move, but I expect you're right that it wouldn't.